# How to get the amount of days on a month or the last day of the month ? Automation Anywhere

Tags: automationanywhere

I need to get the last day of the month, I've tried to run a VB script but I might be using this tool wrong or maybe I'm really bad with VB...

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend looking into https://botstore.automationanywhere.com/bot/change-date-and-time-format/

[image]

This metabot is provided by AA and comes with the functionality you're looking for and then some. Integrating metabots early will aid you in the future when you begin needing them.